# UWP application: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.14.0

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-standard

I have a UWP application built using `.Net Standard 1.4` using `Xamarin` I have recently upgraded a couple of my nuget plugins and my `UWP` project has started giving me the following error:

> "System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.14.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)\r\n"

Now usually this is quite straight forward, you just add a reference to that `.dll`. So I find the nuget package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime/) and add it to my UWP project and build.

Now initially on the nuget package page I cant see a Version `4.0.14` but I install the latest (4.3.0) anyway.

But I still get the same error and when I check the `bin` folder for the version of that library it reports `V4.0.12` so where do I get the V4.0.14 of this library from?

**Extra Info**

The only mention of this version of the dll I can find on the internet is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/3644#issuecomment-343339458)

> The update was only was published as part of
>   Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform and you have to target Fall
>   Creator's Update or higher for the APIs I have listed above. That gets
>   you the following version of the assembly (4.0.3.0 is the latest
>   standalone):
>
> System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.14.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> So scratch .NET 4.6.1 and .NET Core 2.0- only Universal Windows
>   Platform 10.0.16299 for now.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with exact same error message. if you find a solution, please share.

Comment: @batmaci just a couple of questions out of interest; When did this error start occurring? and do you use the Xamarin.Forms plugin `Rg.Popup`?

Comment: yes, I use Rg.popup, It started happening to be honest, i dont know because I have been working on Android recently but updating nugets for entire solution. Just today I looked into UWP project so I found this error. why you think it is Rg.popup?

Comment: do you have project.json.lock file in your uwp project? hidden probably.

Comment: @batmaci do you use a pre release version of `Rg.Popup`? and what version do you use. This error only happens on my branch which I was upgrading `rg.popup` but at this stage its just a hunch.

Comment: 1.1.3.73pre version

Comment: this is the only change I have done updating from creators update to fall creators update. it can be the main reason

Comment: when I open Project.lock.json file, i can find the reference for System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.14.0

Comment: @batmaci try the answer I just posted and let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this version of the library has not been released as an independent package.

The only way you can get this library is to put your Target Version and Min Version to `Fall Creators Update` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/3644#issuecomment-343339458)

> The update was only was published as part of
>   Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform and you have to target Fall
>   Creator's Update or higher for the APIs I have listed above. That gets
>   you the following version of the assembly (4.0.3.0 is the latest
>   standalone):
>
> System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.14.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

This is caused (in my case) by updating the plugin [Rg.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/tree/master/src/Demo/Demo.UWP) to version 1.1.3.73-pre I'm guessing because they use part of the API that isn't available in an earlier build of windows. I have also filed this as a bug report against the Rg.Popup plugin [here](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/217)

I'm pretty sure it's down to microsoft to release that version as a seperate package

To clarify - changing the Target version and min version from Windows 10 Build 10240 to fall creators update fixed the issue for me

Comment: Is that only valid for.net standard2.0 ? because I am still not using .net standard on one of my project and having this problem as well. As I investigated it should be not required to set min as Fall Creators Update if I am not using net standard but sitll profile259 or profile111

Comment: @batmaci I am using `.Net Standard 1.4`

Comment: ah ok, i just read somewhere earlier, it was the thing with 2.0 even you dont have rg.popup or any other thing.

Comment: The min version of UWP changed to fall creators update works. Much appreciated.
I use WebSocket4Net in UWP but it throws exactly the same exception at runtime when websocket opens. 
This min version change saves me.