# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am running a UWP app for windows iot core.  I dropped in some code from a .net framework.  I have converted most of the errors that occurred (most was compatible with the new update build 16299).  I am now getting the error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I keep seeing in some of the nuget packages i have installed:
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.0.6 that 
System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime (>= 4.0.11) is covered.

I am not sure why it is looking for v 4.0.0.0.

Saw this thread but its slightly different: [UWP application: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211211/uwp-application-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-windowsruntime/48211943#48211943?newreg=47d4b05187264d008b7743841f043cb5)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check your packages.config. v4.0.0.0 might be listed in there instead of 4.0.11.

Comment: Where is the packages.config located in vs2017 uwp project?  Sorry if this is a dumb question

Comment: Doesn't .netcore(uwp) use package reference instead of packages.config?  Maybe that's why I dont see a file?

Comment: This is the detail of the file that is throwing the error:
Locating source for 'E:\A\_work\1127\s\src\mscorlib\src\System\RuntimeHandles.cs'. (No checksum.)

The file 'E:\A\_work\1127\s\src\mscorlib\src\System\RuntimeHandles.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'E:\A\_work\1127\s\src\mscorlib\src\System\RuntimeHandles.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'E:\A\_work\1127\s\src\mscorlib\src\System\RuntimeHandles.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.

Comment: The error mentioned in the comment is not same with original post. Was the orignal issue wax fixed? And based on the latest comment, are you building the .Net Core yourself?