# Why does error occur while debugging .MAUI app in Windows with just default code?

Tags: maui, maui-windows

With a brand-new MAUI project (just default code), I try to run the Debug in Windows and receive the following error:

> Deployment failed. FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0.

A pop-up with the information indicating I need to go to the configuration manager and check the "Deploy" checkbox.  Of course, it is already checked.  When I debug in the Android emulator it works just fine. Is MAUI broken for Windows? Why does it not load the appropriate version needed? Can you help.  I have had the same issue in WPF in the past and it seems to be a reoccurring thing.

Comment: This might be the issue on the Visual Studio. You can try to reinstall it.

Comment: I have reinstalled VS 2022 a couple of times without luck.  I have also attempted to create new projects with the same result. Android always works and windows does not.  same error each time.

Comment: I found some related issues and they all caused by the nuget package version. You can refer to this answer about [Cannot load file or assembly 'System.Runtime'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/902363/cannot-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime) and [UWP application: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48211943/19335715).

Comment: The article is similar but, from 2017 and for UWP.  They indicate I should change the minimum target to Fall Creator's Update.  That selection does not exist in MAUI. It does point to the nuget package however.  You would think that after 6 years this issue would have been already resolved.

Comment: It is recommended to report this issue on the GitHub. You can make a new issue thread.